# Django slugfield 'numbers, letters, underscores and hyphens' doesn't seem to be enforced

Tags: django, validation, django-nonrel

I have a model like the following:

```
class Page(ContentBase):    
    url_slug = models.SlugField()
```

Per the SlugField docs, slugfields are 'numbers, letters, underscores and hyphens'. However I seem to be able to set bad slugs which have characters outside that spec:

```
page = Page.objects.get(id=872)
page.url_slug = '&*()&*(*(Y*'    
page.save()

In [26]: page.url_slug
Out[26]: '&*()&*(*(Y*'
```

Why is this? Should the SlugFields actually be validating its input per the docs, or do I need to do this myself? Why does the documentation state the limit when I seem to be able to avoid it so easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SlugField's validation works through it's matching [**forms**.SlugField](https://bitbucket.org/django/django/src/1640f4c5fbe1/django/forms/fields.py#cl-981):

```
class SlugField(CharField):
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _(u"Enter a valid 'slug' consisting of letters, numbers,"
                     u" underscores or hyphens."),
    }
    default_validators = [validators.validate_slug]
```

If you modify it manually without a form, refer to [django.core.validators.validate_slug](https://bitbucket.org/django/django/src/1640f4c5fbe1/django/forms/fields.py#cl-981):

```
slug_re = re.compile(r'^[-\w]+$')
validate_slug = RegexValidator(slug_re, _(u"Enter a valid 'slug' consisting of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens."), 'invalid')
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd heard of the ModelForm before - I don't particularly like it as it means rules aren't consistent between, say, someone saving a form on a page and a unit test.